# Friend function and protected data

Tags: c++, object, friend

I have class

```
    class ScoreBoard: public die
{ //..//
    protected:
    bool mSetValue[6];
    public:
//...//
        friend void ValueSet();
};
```

and I would like to use that friendship to get access to `mSetValue`.
So what I do in `ScoreBoard.cpp` is: I predifine a funcion (`void ValueSet();`) and then define it like this:

```
void ValueSet()
{ char lPick;
std::cin >> lPick;
if (lPick == 1) mSetValue[0] = true; }
```

But the debugger says:

> 'mSetValue' was not declared in this scope.

So, my question is - how to properly set a friendship so `ValueSet` can get access to `mSetValue` array?

Comment: You need an *object* to access its member.

Comment: On an unrelated note: in what way is a scoreboard similar to a die?

Comment: Why should it be similiar? Scoreboard inheritances from die class to have access to it's public methods.

Comment: @PawełMotyka: What `molbdnilo` is trying to say is that inheritance is usually used to indicate an `is-a` relationship for the types. So your inheritance indicates that `ScoreBoard is-a die`

Comment: I'd be quite surprised that this program compiles. Are you sure that the **debugger** says anything?

Comment: You don't use inheritance for accessing methods. In particular not the public methods, as they are accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Member variables<sup>†</sup> exist inside instances (objects). They are also called "instance variables". If there is no instance of the class, then there is no instance variable.

`mSetValue` is a member variable of `ScoreBoard`. Therefore `ScoreBoard::mSetValue` instances exists only within an instance of `ScoreBoard`.

> how to properly set a friendship so ValueSet can get access to mSetValue array?

In function `void ValueSet()` you don't have any instances of `ScoreBoard`. You cannot access `ScoreBoard::mSetValue` - regardless of its access specifier or friendship - because it doesn't exist. What you need is an instance of `ScoreBoard`.

> I use this function inside the ScoreBoard class so I can't create any instance of ScoreBoard inside it

Nothing prevents you from creating an instance of `ScoreBoard` within a member function of `ScoreBoard`. Although, within a member function of `ScoreBoard` you already have access to an instance, which is pointed by `this`, so there might be no need to create a new instance. What you should do depends on your intention.

Given your comment, I suspect that a member function would be more appropriate for you, rather than a free function.

<sup>†</sup> I use the generic term "Member variable" to refer non-static member variables for simplicity. Static member variables are different. They are also called class variables.

Comment: Ok, but I use this function inside the ScoreBoard class so I can't create any instance of ScoreBoard inside it. I though of static variable ( because they are "immortal") but this idea is not working either. Is there any way I can you it inside the function or I have to use the ValueSet funcion in main ?

Comment: @PawełMotyka see the edited answer. I suspect that a  member function would be more appropriate for you, rather than a free function.

Answer (score 1):

Friend functions are not member of class. So in your case if you want to use `mSetValue` in `ValueSet` then you have to provide some access to `mSetValue` via an instance or "object" of that class. This can be done by declaring your `ValueSet()` function as

```
friend void ValueSet(ScoreBoard &sb);
```

And your definition as

```
void ValueSet(ScoreBoard &sb)
{
    char lPick;
    std::cin >> lPick;
    if (lPick == 1)
        sb.mSetValue[0] = true; 
}
```